# tinymce 4 dropdown list doesn't cover button

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

Tinymce plugin v4 doesn't hide the button for font after clicking on it to select the new font. This happens to all selectbox elements if the plugin is not on the top of the page.

Here is my code and an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test tiny mce</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button style="width:30%;height:300px">test</button>
<textarea width="50%"></textarea>
<button style="width:30%;height:300px">test2</button>
<script>tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  
  plugins: "paste,lists,code,insertdatetime,preview, textcolor colorpicker, pagebreak",
  menubar: "",

  paste_as_text: true,
  paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2",
   toolbar: [
    'bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect'  , "nonbreaking",
    'paste pastetext | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo code | insertdatetime preview | forecolor backcolor, textcolor colorpicker',

  ],

    code_dialog_width: 300,
    code_dialog_height: 300,
    //branding:false,
    statusbar:false,
  //width : 300,
  //max_height : 100
});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could make a running example of this issue on TinyMCE Fiddle?

Comment: I use version 4.8.2
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/h3gaab

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing appears to be a defect that was fixed in a newer release of TinyMCE.  If you update your TinyMCE Fiddle to use 4.8.4 or 4.8.5 this issue no longer exists.

Comment: I saw that in versions above 4.8.4 this bug doesn't appear but i wanted tot know if i could fix this locally on version 4.8.4, without changing the version

Comment: I guess you could look at all the commits that happened since 4.8.2 and try to re-apply them to 4.8.2 but why would you want to do that as opposed to just update the editor and be done?  Seems like a lot of unnecessary work.